# Attributed string font color is not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring, nsattributedescription

I am trying to set the font color and its not working for some reason

```cs
public void ConvertToLinkButton(UIButton btn, String hyperlink)
{
    CTStringAttributes attributesHyperLink = new CTStringAttributes();
    attributesHyperLink.UnderlineStyle = CTUnderlineStyle.Single;
    attributesHyperLink.ForegroundColor = UIColor.Purple.CGColor;

    NSMutableAttributedString attrString = new NSMutableAttributedString(btn.TitleLabel.Text);
    attrString.AddAttributes(attributesHyperLink, new NSRange(btn.TitleLabel.Text.IndexOf(hyperlink), hyperlink.Length));
    btn.TitleLabel.AttributedText = attrString;
}
```

It makes me wonder why is it happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try UIKit's [UIStringAttributes](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIStringAttributes/) instead of CoreText's CTStringAttributes.

```cs
UIStringAttributes attributesHyperLink = new UIStringAttributes();
attributesHyperLink.UnderlineStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.Single;
attributesHyperLink.ForegroundColor = UIColor.Purple.CGColor;
```

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H Honestly, I'm not sure. However, CoreText is a low-level technology that is more suitable for cases where you really need low-level text handling features. UIKit's UIStringAttributes provides everything you need here and that's what I've used before.